# Show Details of an Object while allowing interactions with it and dependent objects

Tags: java, jsf-2

## Description

To make it simple, this code is the Controller Packet corresponding to a View with multiple tabs. All but one of these tabs are showing a list of dependent entries. This Construction was once a single class, that did **everything** and I thought "Why not refactor that thing?"

So I began to extract functionality. Then I realized: "Hey the `@SessionScoped` on this thing makes it harder than it should be" and moved to `@ConversationScoped` and `@RequestScoped` respectively.

By the way, the `*Distributor businessInterface` is a wrapper for operating on the Data-Layer Services, that were [subject of a previous question of mine.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46194/datalayer-interfaces-genericized) Even though there is no **real** business Logic there, there was a need to refactor it out to clarify the usage of these classes. (They were also responsible for that, and thus violated SRP)...

The Pages-class mentioned in all these redirects contains constant Strings that are navigation rules for JSF.

#### Did I do well?

**Class Summary (331 lines in 6 files, making a total of 8985 bytes)**

- CustomerDetailsAddressTabController.java: Responsible for all that's happening in the Address Tab of the View.
- CustomerDetailsContactPersonTabController.java: Responsible for ... ContactPerson Tab of the View.
- CustomerDetailsContractTabController.java: .... Contract Tab (*you get it, right?*)
- CustomerDetailsController.java: This one is different. He keeps the current instance of Customer in the Conversation. That's why he is the first with `@ConversationScoped`
- CustomerDetailsProjectsTabController.java: Projects Tab...
- CustomerDetailsTabChangeController.java: This one is also different. He keeps track of which Tab is currently active in the View. Thus he's also `@ConversationScoped`.

## Code

**CustomerDetailsAddressTabController.java:** (74 lines, 2009 bytes)

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class CustomerDetailsAddressTabController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3857482696303153934L;

    @Inject
    IAddressService addressService;

    @Inject
    CustomerDetailsController customerDetailsController;

    @Inject
    AddressEditController addressEditController;

    @Inject
    Resources resources;

    public void promoteToMainLocation(long newMainId) {
        try {
            addressService.promoteToMainAddress(newMainId);
            customerDetailsController.reloadCurrentCustomer();
        } catch (DataLayerLockException e) {
            resources
                    .produceFacesContext()
                    .addMessage(
                            null,
                            new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                    "Error:",
                                    "Some meaningful german error message I censored ;)"));
        }
    }

    public String editAddress(long addrId) {
        redirectToAddressView(addrId);
        return Pages.ADDRESS_EDIT;
    }

    public String deleteAddress(long addrId) {
        processDeleteAddress(addrId);
        return Pages.CUSTOMER_DETAILS;
    }

    private void processDeleteAddress(long addrId) {
        addressService.delete(addrId);
        customerDetailsController.reloadCurrentCustomer();
    }

    public String addAddress() {
        redirectToAddressView(0);
        return Pages.ADDRESS_EDIT;
    }

    public void redirectToAddressView(long addressId) {
        addressEditController.recieveAddress(addressId,
                customerDetailsController.getCustomerId(), Pages.CUSTOMER_DETAILS);
    }
}
```

**CustomerDetailsContactPersonTabController.java:** (49 lines, 1434 bytes)

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class CustomerDetailsContactPersonTabController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 485782696303153934L;

    @Inject
    ContactPersonEditController contactPersonEditController;

    @Inject
    CustomerDetailsController customerDetailsController;

    @Inject
    ContactPersonDistributor businessInterface;

    public String addContactPerson() {
        return redirectToContactPersonView(0);
    }

    public String editContactPerson(final long contactPersonId) {
        return redirectToContactPersonView(contactPersonId);
    }

    private String redirectToContactPersonView(final long contactPersonId) {
        contactPersonEditController.recieveContactPersonById(contactPersonId,
                customerDetailsController.getCustomerId(),
                Pages.CUSTOMER_DETAILS);
        return Pages.CONTACTPERSON_EDIT;
    }

    public String deleteContactPerson(final long contactPersonId) {
        businessInterface.delete(contactPersonId);
        customerDetailsController.reloadCurrentCustomer();
        return Pages.CUSTOMER_DETAILS;
    }

}
```

**CustomerDetailsContractTabController.java:** (46 lines, 1350 bytes)

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class CustomerDetailsContractTabController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4857482696383153934L;

    @Inject
    ContractEditController contractEditController;

    @Inject
    CustomerDetailsController customerDetailsController;

    @Inject
    ContractDistributor businessInterface;

    public String addContract() {
        contractEditController.recieveCustomerToEditContracts(
                customerDetailsController.getCustomerId(), 0l,
                Pages.CUSTOMER_DETAILS);
        return Pages.CONTRACT_EDIT;
    }

    public String editContract(final long contractId) {
        contractEditController.recieveCustomerToEditContracts(
                customerDetailsController.getCustomerId(), contractId,
                Pages.CUSTOMER_DETAILS);
        return Pages.CONTRACT_EDIT;
    }

    public String deleteContract(final long contractId) {
        businessInterface.delete(contractId);
        customerDetailsController.reloadCurrentCustomer();
        return Pages.CUSTOMER_DETAILS;
    }
}
```

**CustomerDetailsController.java:** (66 lines, 1578 bytes)

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class CustomerDetailsController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 48574826963021334L;

    private Customer customer = new Customer();

    @Inject
    Conversation conversation;

    @Inject
    CustomerDetailsTabChangeController tabController;

    @Inject
    CustomerDistributor businessInterface;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (!conversation.isTransient()) {
            conversation.end();
        }
        conversation.setTimeout(120000);
        conversation.begin();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void close() {
        conversation.end();
    }

    public void recieveCustomerById(final long id) {
        this.customer = businessInterface.loadSingle(id);
        tabController.setActiveTab(0);
    }

    public void reloadCurrentCustomer() {
        if (this.customer != null && !(this.customer.getId() <= 0)) {
            recieveCustomerById(this.customer.getId());
        }
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public long getCustomerId() {
        return customer.getId();
    }
}
```

**CustomerDetailsProjectsTabController.java:** (66 lines, 1866 bytes)

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class CustomerDetailsProjectsTabController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 485734534533153934L;

    @Inject
    ProjectEditController projectEditController;

    @Inject
    CustomerDetailsController customerDetailsController;

    @Inject
    CustomerListController customerListController;

    @Inject
    ProjectDetailsController projectDetailsController;

    @Inject
    ProjectDistributor businessInterface;

    public String addProject() {
        return redirectToProjectView(0);
    }

    public String editProject(final long projectId) {
        return redirectToProjectView(projectId);
    }

    private String redirectToProjectView(final long projectId) {
        projectEditController.recieveCustomerToEditProjects(projectId,
                customerDetailsController.getCustomerId(),
                Pages.CUSTOMER_DETAILS);
        return Pages.PROJECT_EDIT;
    }

    public String deleteProject(final long projectId) {
        try {
            businessInterface.delete(projectId);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ent) {
            // that one was already deleted.
        }
        return Pages.CUSTOMER_DETAILS;
    }

    public String showProjectDetails(final long projectId) {
        customerDetailsController.recieveCustomerById(customerDetailsController
                .getCustomerId());
        projectDetailsController.recieveProject(projectId);
        return Pages.PROJECT_DETAILS;
    }
}
```

**CustomerDetailsTabChangeController.java:** (30 lines, 748 bytes)

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class CustomerDetailsTabChangeController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 48574825445153934L;
    private int index;

    public int getActiveTab() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setActiveTab(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
        TabView tabView = (TabView) event.getComponent();
        index = tabView.getChildren().indexOf(event.getTab());
    }
}
```

## Questions

1. Scoping: Can that be improved further? Where could I reduce further, to save even more system resources ;) (the larger the scope, the more difficult it is to maintain)
2. Names: Are these names easily understandable?
3. **Anything else**

I'd also like you to not mention the String error message, I know that one needs a Constant, but as this is still in development, I decided not to extract that yet ;)

Also I gladly provide any further required information ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Scoping :

In your controllers are all your services default scoped.
In mine humble oppinion make them private, if you wish to have the default scope make getters and setters default scope.
**Why:** You easily can forget the private before a global variable but getters/setters are mostly autogenerated public so normally when these are not public it's ment to be.

### Final's :

What is looking odd is that in `CustomerDetailsAddressTabController.java` you don't have the `long addrId` marked as final as you do that in your other controllers.

### Error handling :

```
} catch (DataLayerLockException e) {
    resources
            .produceFacesContext()
            .addMessage(
                    null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                            "Error:",
                            "Some meaningful Error message ;)"));
}
```

A **bigger** problem here is that you don't log the `DataLayerLockException`.
It vanish in thin air cause you don't use the `e` in the catch. 
Succes with finding the problem at that time.