# Replacing strings of blanks by tabs and blanks to achieve same spacing

Tags: c, strings, formatting

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000    /* Maximum length of a line */
#define TABSTOP 4       /* Length of tabstop */

int getLine(char line[], int limit);
int lookAhead(char line[], int start, int end);

    /*
     * Exercise 1-21
     * Write a program entab that replaces strings of blanks
     * by the minimum number of tabs and blanks to achieve the
     * same spacing.
     */

int main(void)
{
    int tabIndex, i;
    char line[MAXLINE];

    while ((getLine(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        i = 0;
        while (line[i] != '\0') {
            if (line[i] == ' ') {
                tabIndex = i + (TABSTOP - (i % TABSTOP)); 
                if ((lookAhead(line, i + 1, tabIndex)) == 1) {
                    putchar('\t');
                    i = tabIndex;
                } else {
                    putchar(line[i]);
                    ++i; 
                }
            } else {
                putchar(line[i]);
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int getLine(char line[], int limit)
{
    int inputVal, i;

    for (i=0; i < (limit - 1) && (inputVal = getchar()) != EOF &&
            inputVal != '\n'; ++i) {
        line[i] = inputVal;
    }
    if (inputVal == '\n') {
        line[i] = inputVal;
        ++i;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

int lookAhead(char line[], int start, int end)
{
    int i, clearPath;

    clearPath = 1;
    for (i = start; i < end; ++i) {
        if (line[i] != ' '){
            clearPath = 0;
        }
    }
    return clearPath;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think a proper `getline()` function should return an `int`, whether it's based on the attempted read (a boolean) or something else.

I believe you're trying to imitate [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets), which instead returns a `char*` (the extracted file line) if the read was successful or `NULL` if it failed.  A proper I/O function should set an error flag upon a failed read attempt, and this is not done by returning an `int`.  Plus, there will be issues if the caller of your function expects a string or a `failbit`, which *should* be the case if the caller expects proper feedback.

Unless `fgets()` *really* doesn't satisfy your needs here, I'd recommend using that or another library function that handles this properly.  Recreating an I/O function can cause problems if not written carefully, and even then you shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: The chapter has you build bare bones versions of several std lib functions which is why I included them. I believe the usage of std lib functions will be detailed in later chapters. Perhaps I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @ao2130: Yes, that would be a good idea, but at least you've learned something about it. :-)

Comment: @Jama Curious, do you consider `fgets()` an improper I/O function because it does not, per C spec, set an error flag anymore than OP's `getLine()`.  Maybe `NULL` is an error flag in that context?

Comment: @chux: I think it's okay in regards to error flags.  The OP's function, however, doesn't return `NULL` at all, so the calling code won't know if an error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have two ways of interpreting "to achieve the same spacing":

1. Replace consecutive space anywhere in a line.
2. Replace only spaces at the beginning of a line that occur before any non-space character.

Either way, this is a **very difficult problem** to solve correctly.  You'll need to implement a complete tab-stop interpreter.  In addition, with Interpretation #1, you may need to implement a source code parser, if your goal is to be able to retab source code without corrupting literal strings that may be embedded in the text.

---

Consider the following input text as an example:

```
/*
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R
012301230123012301230123012301230123012301230123012301230123012301230123
*/
var␣d␣=␣b␣*␣b␣-␣4␣*␣a␣*␣c;␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣//␣discriminant⏎
if (d␣>=␣0)␣{␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣//␣only␣real␣solutions⏎
␣␣␣␣var␣root1␣=␣(-b␣+␣sqrt(d))␣/␣(2␣*␣a);␣␣␣//␣the␣larger␣root⏎
␣␉  var␣root2␣=␣(-b␣+␣sqrt(d))␣/␣(2␣*␣a);␣␣␣//␣the␣smaller␣root⏎
}⏎
```

I believe that the first line should get five <kbd>Tab</kbd>s, with the first <kbd>Tab</kbd> representing just two spaces (G2 and G3).  Also, the `var root2` line has a superfluous leading space that should be discarded.

With Interpretation #1, the output should be:

```
var␣d␣=␣b␣*␣b␣-␣4␣*␣a␣*␣c;␉␉␉␉␉//␣discriminant⏎
if (d␣>=␣0)␣{␉␉␉␉␉␉␉␉//␣only␣real␣solutions⏎
␉var␣root1␣=␣(-b␣+␣sqrt(d))␣/␣(2␣*␣a);␉//␣the␣larger␣root⏎
␉var␣root2␣=␣(-b␣+␣sqrt(d))␣/␣(2␣*␣a);␉//␣the␣smaller␣root⏎
}⏎
```

With Interpretation #2, the output would be:

```
var␣d␣=␣b␣*␣b␣-␣4␣*␣a␣*␣c;␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣//␣discriminant⏎
if (d␣>=␣0)␣{␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣//␣only␣real␣solutions⏎
␉var␣root1␣=␣(-b␣+␣sqrt(d))␣/␣(2␣*␣a);␣␣␣//␣the␣larger␣root⏎
␉var␣root2␣=␣(-b␣+␣sqrt(d))␣/␣(2␣*␣a);␣␣␣//␣the␣smaller␣root⏎
}⏎
```

---

There is a case to be made for interpretation #2, which is more conservative about which spaces are safe to replace while achieving the "same" spacing.  Here is a [real-life example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/41214/9357) of a bug that was introduced due to a careless spaces-to-tabs transformation that meddled with a literal string within some source code.  If there is any doubt about correctness and safety, I think a good policy is to leave the text untransformed.

Answer (score 0):

Minor: `int getLine(char line[], int limit)`

Following code has trouble if `limit` is small as `inputVal` is tested without prior setting and `line[i]` is not known to be in range.

```
int inputVal;
...
if (inputVal == '\n') {
    line[i] = inputVal;
    ++i;
}
line[i] = '\0';
```

Suggest:

```
// top of function
if (limit < 1) return 0;
int inputVal = 0;
...
if (i < (limit - 1) && inputVal == '\n') {
    line[i] = inputVal;
    ++i;
}
```

A re-write of this function could be

```
size_t getLine(char line[], size_t limit) {
    if (limit < 1) return 0;
    limit--;  // Room for \0

    size_t i = 0;
    int inputVal;
    while (i < limit && (inputVal = getchar()) != EOF) {
        line[i] = inputVal;
        ++i;
        if (inputVal == '\n') break;
    }

    line[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```