# Shell script for creating CR questions

Tags: formatting, shell, stackexchange, sh

Inspired by [Tool for creating CodeReview questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41198).

This script generates a markdown document suitable for a CR question from a list of files. For each file it finds, it sends the following to stdout:

- The relative path to the file, in bold.
- The byte count and line count, in parentheses.
- The contents of the file, indented four spaces on each line.

**./mdproj.sh** (186 bytes in 7 lines)

```
for path in $(find "$@"); do
    bytes="$(wc -c < "$path") bytes"
    lines="$(wc -l < "$path") lines"
    echo -e "\n**$path** ($bytes in $lines)\n"
    sed "s/^/    /" < "$path"
done
```

The script takes the same options as `find`. Example usage:

```
mdproj.sh -name *.h -or -name *.cpp > whatever.md
```

---

**Update / known issues**

- No spaces, backquotes, backslashes, asterisks, or other weird characters are allowed in file names.
- Watch out for shell expansion when invoking the script. Arguments should be enclosed in quotes in cases where the the shell would expand them.

Comment: Now who will make a `.bat` version of this? :)

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be possible with the tools that ship with Windows; probably needs some things from GnuWin32 or similar

Comment: Use cygwin FTW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I note three potential problems with your approach, both dealing with special characters in filenames, as well as  one comment on the example usage.

## `for` with `find`

Consider a directory structure where some paths have spaces in them, say:

```
Source
├── Constants.h
└── Main Loop.c
```

(One could argue the wisdom of using spaces in paths, but your script should be able to deal with them anyway.) What would `find . -type f` output?

```
./Source/Constants.h
./Source/Main Loop.c
```

What would `for path in $(find . -type f); do echo $path; done` output?

```
./Source/Constants.h
./Source/Main
Loop.c
```

That's right; `for` splits on whitespace, breaking your paths. This is [a notorious issue](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Fortunately, that page provides a solution:

```sh
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' path; do echo $path; done
```

## `echo -e`

Look at this line:

```sh
echo -e "\n**$path** ($bytes in $lines)\n"
```

You're substituting `path` in, and then telling `echo` to interpret the resulting text. That suggests that if `path` has an escape sequence in it, `echo` will interpret it. Indeed, it does:

```sh
% path='x\ay'
% touch "$path"
% echo -e "$path"
xy
```

(The `\a` was interpreted as "sound the bell.") Instead of using `echo -e`, consider passing the special characters directly to `echo`. You can make Bash interpret ones before passing it to `echo` by using `$''`:

```sh
% echo $'\n'"**$path** ($bytes in $lines)"$'\n'
```

## Markdown

Markdown cares about special names, too. What if I had a file named `a** b **c`? Your script would give me a header:

```sh
**a** b **c**
```

> **a** b **c**

But that's probably not what you intended. You probably want to enclose it in backticks:

```sh
**`a** b **c`**
```

> **`a** b **c`**

But even that's not enough. What if my file names have backticks, like, say, `` a` b `c ``?

```sh
**`a` b `c`**
```

> **`a` b `c`**

That's no good! You have to then double-backtick it:

```sh
**``a` b `c``**
```

> **`` a` b `c ``**

Essentially, you have to count the maximum number of consecutive backticks and enclose it in that-number-plus-one of backticks.

## Example usage

You suggest

```sh
mdproj.sh -name *.h -or -name *.cpp > whatever.md
```

but that will only work when there are exactly zero or one files whose name end with `.h` and exactly zero or one files whose name end with `.cpp`. Consider how it expands when there are no files:

```sh
mdproj.sh -name *.h -or -name *.cpp > whatever.md
```

That's right; Bash leaves them in place, passing them on to `find`, where *it* looks for files of the form `*.h` and `*.cpp`. Since there are no such files (otherwise, Bash would have substituted them in) `find` will not find the files, and so nothing will happen. What if there is `example.h` and `example.cpp`?

```sh
mdproj.sh -name example.h -or -name example.cpp > whatever.md
```

That works fine. What if there are multiple?

```sh
mdproj.sh -name foo.h bar.h -or -name foo.cpp bar.cpp > whatever.md
```

Uh oh. `-name` takes only one value, but you're passing it two. My `find` dies with this error:

```sh
find: bar.h: unknown option
```

I always use `-regex` for that sort of thing:

```sh
mdproj.sh -regex '.*\.h' -or -regex '.*\.cpp' > whatever.md
```

(If I was being cleverer, I might use `-E` and merge them into one regular expression.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments! re: "that will only work when there are exactly zero or one files whose name end with .h and exactly zero or one files whose name end with .cpp." -- I might be reading this wrong, but it does work with multiple files. Am I misunderstanding you? When I run this the shell does not expand `*.foo`, it gets passed through as a pattern to `find`.

Comment: @Dagg: The shell expands it and breaks the command for me. With `a.h`, `b.h`, `a.cpp`, and `b.cpp` in the current working directory, I get `find: b.h: unknown option`. It does, however, work if they are in a subdirectory rather than the current working directory.

Comment: Ah, yes, all of my code was in a subdirectory, so of course it wasn't expanding it. Silly mistake :)